# Type hint a field that can be None with a default value

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

When using Python 3.10 in PyCharm and type hinting my methods I am noticing something that confuses me a bit and I am looking for the correct approach and also understanding what causes the following.

If I have this method:

```
def my_method(value: str = None) -> None:
    ...
```

and I try to call it from a different place, placing the cursor inside the brackets in the method and using the CMD + P (MacOS - Main Menu | View | Code Editor View Actions | Code View Actions | Parameter Info shortcut) I am seeing that the parameter typing is automatically recognised as:

```
value: str | None = None
```

From everything I've read online the correct way to achieve type hinting a parameter which is None or a string with None by default would be one of these:

```
value: str | None = None # modern 3.10+ syntax
value: typing.Union[str, None] = None
value: typing.Optional[str] = None # alias for the previous one
```

Is this something that is PyCharm specific in my case? How does it work? As far as I understand they have their own engine that looks at autocomplete, hinting etc.. Would it be incorrectly interpreted as a str in other editors? I also tested VS Code where it gives me the method definition as `value: str = None`
but I also don't get a warning if I define the method as
`value: str` and then call it with `method(None)` which in PyCharm shows up as a warning.

Comment: This is such a common idiom, type checkers don't require you to explicitly say `Optional[str]` or `str | None`. Specifying `None` as the default value automatically implies this.

Comment: hm, pyright doesn't seem to do that automatically, though

Comment: That is a commonly used idiom, but it is of course strictly speaking not correct and a union should be preferred. `mypy --strict` will actively discourage you from omitting the `None` from the type union for example. Then again, `None` is not even a type at all, so it is strictly speaking not correct to use as such in the first place... Yet that _is_ the norm. I guess you have to draw the line _somewhere_ considering both practicality and correctness. This may be the reason why I still prefer `Optional[T]` to the explicit union.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg "*None is not even a type at all, so it is strictly speaking not correct...*"—Using None as a type hint for the nonetype is part of [the standard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#using-none), so it *is* correct, even if it's exceptional.

Comment: @khelwood I know it is. I have read PEP 484 and I said that is the norm in the very next sentence. By _correct_ I meant theoretically consistent. `None` is not a type. It is supposed to be considered _equivalent_ to `NoneType` in type annotations. And I am fine with that. I just brought it up as an ironic example of how things that are not entirely consistent are sometimes still accepted because it is easier and "feels" correct enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PEP 484:

> As a shorthand for Union[T1, None] you can write Optional[T1]; for example, the above is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> from typing import Optional
>
> def handle_employee(e: Optional[Employee]) -> None: ...
> ```
>
> A past version of this PEP allowed type checkers to assume an optional type when the default value is None, as in this code:
>
> ```
> def handle_employee(e: Employee = None): ...
> ```
>
> This would have been treated as equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def handle_employee(e: Optional[Employee] = None) -> None: ...
> ```
>
> This is no longer the recommended behavior. Type checkers should move towards requiring the optional type to be made explicit.

As I understand it, this could mean that IDEs could interpret it differently, but is possible that they keep this behaviour for compatibility reasons.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#union-types